# mobile emulators during development

Tags: mobile, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, emulation

Currently developing an mvc4 applications that will need to be optimized for mobile devices etc.

As I develop within visual studio, I would like to be able to test how the site is viewed on an iphone/android same as I can check it on a desktop browser.

Any emulators that come recommended for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Android Emulator from google, it comes with Android SDK.
Some sample/simple sites exists which emulates iPhone, like this:
http://iphone4simulator.com/

See here for other sites:
http://www.practicalecommerce.com/articles/2495-Mobile-Compatibility-How-to-Test-a-Website-for-Mobile-Browsers